# How to handle null values with where clause in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two entities where I `Groupjoin` them into a list and I am trying to search for a match for a certain value in different properties. 
**The problem** is that if one property has null value in the list, the search completly ignores the other properties and returns empty list.

I am posting the relevant code,

**populating `entities`,**

```
List<PatientsRegistrySearchViewModel> SearchList = new List<PatientsRegistrySearchViewModel>(); 
List<PatientsRegistrySearchViewModel> DataResponse = new List<PatientsRegistrySearchViewModel>();
```

**Groupjoin**,

```
SearchList = (
    from p in registryList
    join c in registryAccountsList on p.PatientFileId equals c.PatientFileId into g
    from c in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new PatientsRegistrySearchViewModel {
        PatientFileId = p.PatientFileId,
        Name = p.FirstName,
        AliasName = p.AliasName,
        PatientDob = p.PatientDob.ToString(),
        PatientAge = 0,
        PatientEmail = c?.Email,
        SocialSecurityNo = p.SocialSecurityNo,
        PatientMobileNo = c?.MobileNo
    }).ToList();
```

and my search logic,

```
searchResults = (from i in SearchList where (
    i.Name.ToLower().Contains (value.ToLower()) ||
    i.PatientEmail.ToLower ().Contains (value.ToLower())
) select i).ToList();
```

this search logic will compare the value to `Name` or `PatientEmail`, if either prop is null in the list, the returned result is empty! Why (||) "or" operator is not skipping null?

list example,

```
{
patientFileId: 1111,
Name: "John",
aliasName: null,
patientDob: "1/25/85 12:00:00 AM",
patientAge: 0,
patientEmail: "aamaizar@gmail.com",
socialSecurityNo: "1212121SSN",
patientMobileNo: "3244990"
},
{
patientFileId: 2222,
Name: "Nicole",
aliasName: null,
patientDob: "1/1/01 12:00:00 AM",
patientAge: 0,
patientEmail: null,
socialSecurityNo: null,
patientMobileNo: null
},
{
patientFileId: 3333,
Name: "Nancy",
aliasName: null,
patientDob: "3/25/85 12:00:00 AM",
patientAge: 0,
patientEmail: "aamaizar@gmail.com",
socialSecurityNo: null,
patientMobileNo: "3244990"
}
```

Comment: There does not seem to be EF involved. Did you miss parts, or can the tag be removed?

Comment: If you are really using lists, there is nothing in common with EF Core. And if some property is `null`, `prop.ToLower ().Contains (value.ToLower ()` will simply generate NRE. So why don't you present your real case?

Comment: @IvanStoev, I am removing the ef-core2.0 tag, you are right, its `LINQ` question, my apologies.

Comment: If you want good answers, you should try better formatting your LINQ queries. I did it for you this time.

Comment: @Sefe, much appreciated,  tried to do so using this [site](http://csharpindepth.com/CodeFormatterTool.aspx)

Comment: Please do not write `.Tolist ()`. This space before the brackets reads horrible for me. a = b is ok, Console.WriteLine ("sdf") not.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with the `Contains` there. You are calling `Contains` on a `string`, which means you are looking for a substring within the string. Is this really what you want?

Comment: If `PatientEmail` is null, `PatientEmail.ToLower()` should throw a NullReferenceException. Do you got a `try{...}catch{...}` around it returning a empty list?

Comment: @Sefe, I am trying to get the closest match, i.e. if I am searching "jo" the query should return john record, if I searched "ama" the query should return 2 records that closely match the email address

Comment: @Chriz, I removed the spaces, I am trying to get the closest match here. I am handling the empty list action in my `controller`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I made a small test which made my guess sure.
Code snippet:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var searchList = new List<TwoProps>()
        {
            new TwoProps() {Name = "sdfs1", PatientEmail="mymail@sf.com" },
            new TwoProps() {Name = "sdfs2", PatientEmail=null },
            new TwoProps() {Name = "sdfs3", PatientEmail="mymail2@sf.com" }
        };

        var stringToSearch = "myMail".ToLower();
        var query = (from listItem in searchList
                    where listItem.Name.ToLower().Contains(stringToSearch)
                        || listItem.PatientEmail.ToLower().Contains(stringToSearch)
                    select listItem).ToList(); //NullReferenceException is thrown here @ second element
        //listItem.PatientEmail.ToLower() => null.ToLower() => NRE

        Console.WriteLine(query.Count());
    }

    private class TwoProps
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PatientEmail { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You can fix this with `...|| (listItem.PatientEmail?.ToLower().Contains(stringToSearch) ?? false)`.

As expected, there is a NRE thrown. You are handling the exception somewhere and return a empty list or simply dont populate your list with teh result items(results are the same).

Comment: Sorry I missed the part of your comment with regards to NRE, its not shown but yes in case of NRE i am returning empty list and my controller throws 404.

Comment: This is amazing, Thanks so much

Comment: I'm happy I made your day :)

Comment: You did indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

The `||` operator plus the `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` will INCLUDE values that are `null`. And then you are trying to do a `ToLower()` on a `null` value.

Try this. It will first make sure the valie of email is not null then do the contains.

```
searchResults = (from i in SearchList where (
    i.Name.ToLower ().Contains (value.ToLower ()) ||
    (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (i.PatientEmail) &&
    i.PatientEmail.ToLower ().Contains (value.ToLower ()))
) select i).ToList ();
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
AliasName = p.AliasName,
```

Replace With

```
AliasName = p.AliasName ?? ""
```

When p.AliasName is null, then AliasName is an empty string.

Comment: the query does not look in `AliasName` prop

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: please look at `searchResults` query, `AliasName` prop is not included in the query context

Comment: I dont talk about the variable searchResults. The select new is your problem. You map the p.AliasName to the variable AliasName(PatientsRegistrySearchViewModel).                                 
In the Map you dont make a null check. Make this ?? to get by null, default a empty string.